# Why my app is crashing after first good launch?

Tags: java, android

When i run and install my app in emulator it works fine. Then after i close app and start next times it start crashing.
I have tried to read different questions but didnt help for me

Program read epub/fb2 files and show on screen

Sorry for links but i cant format code properly and question was with error

The stack trace is

```
Process: net.textreaderfb2epub, PID: 6609
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.textreaderfb2epub/net.textreaderfb2epub.fileBrowser.FileBrowser}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader/net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader.TextReader}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader/net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader.TextReader}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
      at net.textreaderfb2epub.fileBrowser.FileBrowser.onCreate(FileBrowser.java:115)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) `
```

**FileBrowser.java**:
 https://pastebin.com/E0SpgnN1

**AndroidManifest.xml** :
https://pastebin.com/rqnjqrFN

Comment: Post the relevant code and stacktrace here.

Comment: logcat tells you what happens, please try to learn how to read an error stacktrace. You have not declared your second activity in the manifest (or you have a typo in setClassName()..

Comment: Probably better to post your code directly in your question rather than in PasteBin, in case PasteBin goes down. Just remember to indent them by 4 spaces first.

Comment: yes i try post code directly but forum give me wrong format error

Comment: @Opiatefuchs https://pastebin.com/rqnjqrFN Manifest

Comment: i think you should check your intent filters for **action** and **category**

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to find explicit activity class {net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader/net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader.TextReader}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I'm willing to bet that you've not added your `TextReader` Activity to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Try adding something like this inside your `<application>` tag:

```
<application ...>
    <activity android:name=".textReader.TextReader">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Rest of your current intent-filter with data params -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: And it's still crashing?

Comment: Same stacktrace reason? (Unable to find explicit activity class)?

Comment: <activity android:name="net.textreaderfb2epub.textReader.TextReader"
i have this in manifest and crash no stoping

Comment: Ok, but is the stacktrace still the same?

Comment: Try adding a second `intent-filter` with just the Category, as in my example. You might need a default `intent-filter` without any `data` parameters

Comment: Can you post your `TextReader` class as well please? Silly question, but just want to make sure that's extending `Activity` too.

Comment: Final thing I can think of, try shortening the `android:name` field to `.textReader.TextReader`